# How to avoid the "mixed content warning" with signalR, on a cross-domain scenario?

Tags: signalr, cross-domain

I'm trying to build a prototype of browser <-> windows app communication, using SignalR.

The objective is simple: I have a tray application running on each client that reads a smart-card and generates a value which should be passed to the web application.

I've built a self-hosted SignalR hub on the tray application and the webpage communicates successfully with it.

Problem is, in production the webapp is delivered over HTTPS and the signalR hub is delivered over classic HTTP (e.g. `http://localhost:8080`) and, as expected, most modern browser throw a mixed-content warning and refuse to talk to signalR.

My questions are:

1) Is there a way to avoid the mixed-content warning?

2) Would it be worth to build a self-hosted http server supporting HTTPS? And, if so, will the browser talk to a client on `https://localhost/` with some self-signed certificate?

Thank you

Comment: Why is the hub delivered over http?

Comment: Hi dfowler. So far, I haven't been able to provide a self hosted HTTP/SSL server in a windows app. I'm using OWIN, perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: I've been following these hints http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/438435 but to no avail. Also, I fear that if my clients have to configure the certificate binding to the https address, (via netsh) they wouldn't be able to install the applications by themselves

Comment: Shouldn't this be architected the other way around? Tray application connects to website (not website connects to tray application). Ultimately the solution will be to use one scheme throughout (ie: https).

Comment: @BenSwayne: I do have to have the rendered page on the user's machine talk to it's computer. This is for "clerical user" to authenticate an incoming customer. The customer presents a RFID card which the application is expecting. That's why the page talks to the tray application. To query the card's data.

Comment: @TiagoMatias Even with your clarification it is still backwards. The tray application should "notify" the webpage that an RFID card was presented and not wait for the web page to query it. The direction should be RFID->Tray App->Web page if I understand correctly (using the tray app to provide hardware access for a webpage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking two questions here:

**Avoid mixed content warnings in IE**
This is easy: Go to Tools -> Internet Options and select the Security tab. Make sure the *Internet* zone is selected and then click the *Custom Level* button. Scroll down to *Display mixed content* and set it to *Enable*.

Be aware that this setting is there for a reason. Changing it carries a security risk, and it applies to all Internet sites you visit. It is not advisable to ask future users of your application to change this setting. However, it is still possible.

All other common browsers allow to change this setting as well.

**Hosting an SSL server with a self-signed certificate**
This is certainly possible. However, be aware that you will face warnings similar to the one above, namely "Untrusted Connection" warnings. They serve to inform the user about a certificate that was not signed by an official Certification Authority.

Creating a self-signed certificate should not be too hard (in fact, you might even re-use the same certificate on multiple machines. This is an acceptable alternative to using unencrypted HTTP). The advantage of this is that users can confirm a security exception once, and not be bothered in the future; also, this would not affect web security when browsing other pages than `localhost`.

Comment: As a side note: Can't you get your tray application to pipe the data to the server? If you can, you'll only have to relay it back to the appropriate client to circumvent all these problems.

Comment: I understand your approach, the tray application does talk to the server and I've thought of that approach. The problem lies in the "relay it back to the appropriate client". 

There is no way to match a particular card reader (on a tray application) to the browser that just happens to be opened on the same desktop, ie. I cannot identify a particular machine through the browser.

Regarding your answer, I'm now realizing that there's always some sort of warning, so probably I'd have to instruct the users to relax their browser's security.